# trigger jQuery code after 10 min on in-activity

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

What would be the best way to monitor activity of a user on the page? I am developing a CMS system and using this as a security feature, if user is inactive for set amount of minutes then jQuery would trigger a function which would trigger whole page overlay and load in login script having to force the user to re-enter the password in-order to reopen the page or else after so many failed attempts PHP would force the user to logout script and destroy entire session.

So here how it would go

***If no activity after 5min***

jQuery(checks user activity every 5min) -> loop <- jQuery(if no activity after 5min) -> function(trigger overlay + authorization script via AJAX)

***If there is activity***

jQuery(checks user activity every 5min) -> loop <- jQuery(if active go back to loop)

So ye this is about it, thanks in advance.

Activity Definition for this script: Movement of mouse or input(keyboard) of text into text fields or clicking elements.

Comment: How do you define activity? The normal way is to have a timer event that is reset when activity occurs ( mousemove maybe, or keyup ). But you need to define "activity" clearly to start with.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat I define activity as mouse movement, something being edited even a single click on show/hide stuff is considered activity. Inactivity is when the mouse has been on one element or specific point of the page and has not been moved in the time, or no text was inputed to input fields.

Comment: TBH, the plugin is your best bet. If that is not suitable, then as I commented above. If you need more details, let me know, and I will put some code together.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's [Idle Timer](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

As Justin says, jQuery does have an idle timer plugin. However, this method is not going to be sufficient alone unless your idle timer also destroys login cookies - your overlay can easily be circumvented by an array of browser plugins, or even (depending on how your application is built) GET parameters.

Reloading the page would even circumvent this "security" unless you log the user out.

Comment: Reloading page would force new session as the entire system is AJAX based and the user does not go out-side of the main.php file. So there for the session is the same, in the even of refresh PHP would force a new session which would force login script. So no way to pass that.

Comment: @Kerin: Even on a 'traditional' site, the idle timer could be used to redirect the browser to a logout page that destroys the session and notifies the user that they have idled-out. My bank, for example, uses a five-minute "no movement" check on their site and a fifteen-minute server-side "no requests" timeout.

Comment: @PT, If reloading the page logs the user out I imagine that might get a mite vexing for your users.  But your mileage may vary.  :)

Comment: @Justin, I'm in agreement with you there.  Did you perhaps mean to reply to PT here?

Comment: @Kerin: Sorry, it's been one of those days today. I'd edit the comment, but there's that pesky five-minute rule.

Comment: @Justin: Not to worry, just threw me for a loop.  Hope your day improves.

Comment: @sudowned a yes my bank does that as well but its server-side, if no activity after so much time it kills the session and when you try to click any link on the page it will send you to a page with login. I can freely do this with PHP just set expiration for sessions and renew them every so often with. Also most of the content is AJAX based to begin with @sudowned so not much is refreshed, plus if you try to reload page you will get a notification asking for confirmation before the refresh idiot proven :) and its only going to ask for pass anyways nothing more.

Comment: If I had to give my password to a site after reloading, I wouldn't use that site anymore.

Comment: @sudowned lol, you most likely missed this part first paragraph at ending "I am developing a CMS system" this is for a CMS not a site, just a double type of security which can be easily disabled at admin's desire. O and trust me I used sites before which have expiration on sessions while I went to make my self coffee my session expired and i had to re-login lol